# Windows 7 explorer crash

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, crash

I am using Windows 7. My explorer crashes approximately once every hour with this error data:

```
Signature issue:
   Problem Event Name: BEX
   Application Name: explorer.exe
   Application Version: 6.1.7601.17514
   Time stamp of the application: 4ce796f3
   The fault module name: StackHash_0a9e
   Fault module version: 0.0.0.0
   Time stamp of the fault module: 00000000
   Shift deviation: 05d9f930
   Exception code: c0000005
   Deviation data: 00,000,008
   OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
   Area ID: 1037
   Additional Information 1: 0a9e
   Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
   Additional Information 3: 0a9e
   Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

What can I do to further investigate what causes this crash?

Comment: I just want to confirm that Windows Explorer is what is crashing.  When it does crash, you lose your desktop, until the process is automatically restarted by Windows.

Comment: The desktop isn't lost, but all folder windows are gone.

Comment: Have you performed the normal steps to verify the integrity of your installation?

Comment: No, where do I find these steps?

Comment: Lets start with `sfc /scannow` within command prompt.

Comment: Ok some repairs took place according to CBS.log
Do you want the entire log? or are there any specific lines?

Comment: Before you post the log.  Does the problem still exist?

Comment: I don't know for sure, I'll have to wait a while and see if it happens again.

Comment: Yes it just happened again.

Comment: How large is the log?  We just need to know what was repaired.

Comment: I've read a few things about this Microsoft update http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2670838 causing stackhash_0a9e errors. I had a similar problem and removing it fixed it for me.

Comment: follow the steps from here and upload the created dump file (compressed as zip): http://pastebin.com/HAh45FFJ